# How does "Neither will I ever again strike down" Genesis 8:21 compare with "strike down the nations" Rev' 19:15?

Tags: revelation

**Genesis 8:21** ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%208%3A21&version=ESV), **emphasis** added)

> And when the LORD smelt the pleasing aroma, the LORD said in his heart, "I will never again curse the ground because of man, for the intention of man's heart is evil from his youth. **Neither will I ever again strike down every living creature** as I have done."

**Revelation 19:15** ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2019%3A15&version=ESV), **emphasis** added)

> From his mouth comes **a sharp sword with which to strike down the nations**, and he will rule them  with a rod of iron. He will tread the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God the Almighty.

In Genesis 8:21 the LORD will not "strike down" again, but in Rev'19:15 The Word of God has  a sharp sword with which to "strike down".

Both events refer to destruction of physical human beings.

How do they compare?

Comment: One of the biggest distinctions is in Genesis that "every living creature" included animals whereas Revelation is only referring to people.

Comment: It seems There's no never or ever word in the original languages Heb or Greek in the Genesis verse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must recall that Genesis was written in Hebrew and Revelation was written in Greek.  The two verbs thus cannot be exactly the same.  However, it is true that they are very similar.

Before discussing why there is no contradiction here, let me review the meaning of the two verbs involved:

- Gen 8:21 - נָכָה (nakah) = smite, or, attack and destroy, afflict
- Rev 19:15 - πατάσσω (patasso) = smite, strike with a sword, afflict

Further, it is also true that while Gen 8:21 says that God struck every living creature, it actually means all living creatures that were not in the ark, ie, the righteous humans and saved animals.  Similarly, Rev 19:15 also means that when God smites the "nations" it does not include the righteous.

Thus, the meaning of the two is very similar indeed.

However, the main difference is rather stark:

- Gen 8:21 is discussing the literal destruction of life (in this case by flood)
- Rev 19:15 is NOT discussing a literal striking of the nations with a literal sword - note the highly figurative language:
- the sword comes from the mouth of Jesus; see Rev 1:16 (and Eph 6:17) which appears to be an allusion to Job 5:15
- Jesus rules with an iron scepter (an allusion to Ps 2:9)
- Jesus treads the winepress of the fury of God (clearly metaphorical) and an allusion back to Rev 14:20
- the wicked nations are actually destroyed by fire (not a literal sword) according to Rev 20:9

Thus, while Gen 8:21 and Rev 19:15 appear contradictory, one is literal and the other figurative.  However, both only apply to the wicked nations.

Comment: The sword that comes from the mouth of Jesus, Hebrews 4:12 "the word of God is living and active" and Rev 1:16 is very different from Psalm 57:4 where "sharp swords" are "cutting and killing reproaches" Benson, ie "sharp swords" here are slanderous attacks. So one sword against the many wins.

Answer (score 1):

## Genesis: annihilation; Revelation: political dominance

From the question:

> Both events refer to destruction of physical human beings.

No, they don't exactly.

From **Genesis 8:21**: ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%208%3A21&version=ESV), ***emphases*** added)

> Neither will I ever again strike down ***every*** living creature ***as I have done***.

That includes 100% of both humans and animals. Note, it didn't include fish even though those are "living creatures". So, there is some expectation that we can figure out what He means.

Also, it was *as He had done*, meaning by way of flooding and/or complete annihilation.

From **Revelation 19:15**: ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2019%3A15&version=ESV), ***emphasis*** added)

> a sharp sword with which to strike down the ***nations***, and ***he will rule them*** with a rod of iron.

The word for "nations" is ἔθνος (ethnos, [Strong's 1484](https://biblehub.com/greek/1484.htm)), from which we get the English word "ethnic" and is often translated "Gentiles". It is a reference to asserting power over people groups arranged by political boundaries and ethnicity.

Also, he will *rule them*, meaning that they have not been completely annihilated.

Comment: If in Rev'19:15 "strike down" does not mean destroyed/killed as they are ruled with a rod of iron, then can we say what has been "struck down"?

Comment: @C.Stroud It could mean something along the lines of political or military power, or only applying to a few with such power.

Comment: If you know Hebrew, is it true that the Genesis verse does not have "never", but simply that I will *not* add more curses or disasters. It refers to the immediate period of stoping the global floods or curses; it doesnt mean the same will not happen

Comment: @Michael16 sadly I don't know Hebrew and can't speak to whether "never" is there as a word or strongly implied. But, I do understand that many teach the passage means something along the lines of what you suggest: stopping global floods or comprehensive destruction is the point, and it doesn't promise that large-scale destruction won't ever happen again, just not comprehensive where all animals survive with one man's family in a boat.

Comment: I have heard that the "never" destroy promise pertains to destruction by water alone. However it seems the translations are just wrong, there's no never in the verse.

Comment: @Michael16 Hebrew doesn't work exactly the way Greek and our Western languages do. Perhaps that itself could be a specific question about where "never" comes from in the Hebrew for that verse specifically. Beyond that, I don't think it only applies to water, but comprehensive annihilation. Specifically, I think God promises that He won't let things go that far ever again, which means that many of the actions He allows are to prevent the need for such annihilation in order to preserve life in the long run. That's yet another topic tho. We somewhat agree on the vagueness of this.